# Login not working (CodeIgniter) but no error

Tags: authentication, codeigniter-3

When you call http://localhost/login the login page will display. When you enter data and hit submit it will redirect to http://localhost/loginuser but nothing else happens. No redirect to dashboard, nothing happens. And I'm asking myself why? Someone any idea?

login_view.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Photography</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css');?>">
</head>
<body>
<div id="bgimglogin">
<div class="centered">
    <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt loginicon"></i>
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION)) {
        echo $this->session->flashdata('flash_data');
    } ?>
    <form id="loginform" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="max_mustermann">

            <label for="password">Passwort</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Passwort">

            <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Anmelden</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <p id="register"><a href="<?php echo site_url("register"); ?>">Registrieren</a></p>
</div>
<footer>
    <p>&copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> by Photography</p>
</footer>
</div>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous">

</script>
<script>
    $("#loginform").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>loginuser",
            data:$("#submitform").serialize(),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {
                window.location.replace("<?php echo base_url(); ?>loginuser")
            }
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

login_controller.php:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class login_controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }


    public function index(){

        if($_POST){

            $result = $this->login_model->pruefe_user($_POST);

            if(!empty($result)){

                $data = array(
                    'id_user' => $result->id,
                    'username' => $result->username
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('dashboard');

            }
            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', 'Passwort oder Name falsch');
                redirect('login');
            }
        }

        $this->load->view('website/login_view');

    }
}
```

login_model.php:

```
<?php
class login_model extends CI_Model {


    public function __construct(){

        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function pruefe_user($data){

        $this->db->where('username', $data['username']);
        $this->db->where('password', md5($data['password']));
        $result = $this->db->get('user')->row();
        return $result;
    }

}
```

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'index_controller/index';
$route['login'] = 'index_controller/login';
$route['register'] = 'index_controller/register';
$route['ref'] = 'index_controller/ref';
$route['contact'] = 'index_controller/contact';
$route['imprint'] = 'index_controller/imprint';
$route['dashboard'] = 'index_controller/dashboard';
$route['loginuser'] = 'login_controller/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't loaded the session in autoload. Now it works.